# How to remove the blue box that appears when i click JButton

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

When i click Button, the blank part of the image  looks blue. Is there any way?

```
        left.setPressedIcon(l1);
        left.setOpaque(false);
        left.setFocusPainted(false);
        left.setBackground(new Color(0,0,0,0));
        left.setBorderPainted(false);
        left.setBounds(-15, 400, 100, 200);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
left.setBackground(new Color(0,0,0,0));
```

Don't attempt to use a transparent color. Swing doesn't paint transparent colors  properly. See: [Backgrounds With Transparency](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/31/backgrounds-with-transparency/).

In any case that is not needed be you are using

```
 left.setOpaque( false );
```

> When i click Button, the blank part of the image looks blue

Try:

```
left.setContentAreaFilled( false );
```

Also:

```
left.setBounds(-15, 400, 100, 200);
```

Don't use setBounds(...) and a null layout. Swing was designed to be used with layout managers.